# unit test in C# with jenkins

Tags: c#, unit-testing, shell, jenkins

I know, that it is possible to get started unit tests in C# on a jenkins server. I am using GIT and my IDE is Eclipse.

As i know, I have to do all the work with shell scripts? Is this true?

I am a beginner, so can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you using for tests? MsTests? Nunit?

Comment: P.S You can get Visual Studio express for free!

Comment: I am working on Linux!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# using Eclipse? wow!

What you need is to find a way of running your tests from command line. Once you have it, create a build script in PowerShell (you can use any shell language, my recommendation is PowerShell) that:

1. Get latest version of code from GIT (Probably you can use GIT plugin in Jenkins)
2. Compile code (Not sure if msbuild can help you here, I think is possible.)
3. Run the unit tests using the previously obtained command line.
4. Configure Jenkins build to report output of tests (usually point to output .htm)

Comment: Ok, lets say, that i have all my tests done. Now, I have installed the GIT Plugin for Jenkins. And I am working on a Debian machine. All I have to do is to get started the test on the command line?

Comment: When you use GIT plugin, it automatically get latest version from GIT for you. After that you should compile the code. In a Debian I guess you should use Mono. Whatever the way you are compiling, use it.

Comment: As you are in linux, use bash, ksh or similar to have an script that compiles code and runs tests. As I have always used windows I am not sure on how you can run the unitests... but whatever the way Eclipse does it you should do it in your build script.

Comment: Maybe you have good reasons to use Debian and eclipse but if this is not the case follow @arran advice, get a vm with windows and use visual studio express...